# query option in COPY postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

According to [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html), I can use query option when exporting data. Can I use query VALUES when loading data into tables from txt file? If I have 2 columns and I want to insert record manually in the first column(SentenceID) and insert data in the second column(Sentence) from text file. Is it something like:

```
    copy foo1(Sentence) | (VALUES (2339)) from '/path/to/sentence.txt' with delimiter '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are trying to combine `COPY` query **values** ( which are relevant only for `COPY ... TO ...` - export data) with `COPY ... FROM ...` (which [by definition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) does accept only ***filename***, ***PROGRAM 'command'***  or ***STDOUT*** but NOT combination of them). In theory you might use ***PROGRAM*** option to select particular column (`SentenceId`), but it still will not allow you to combine several `FROM` options. In other words, I would say it can be only achieved with 2 separate steps:

- insert data into `foo1`.`Sentence` column using `COPY`:

  `COPY foo1(Sentence) FROM '/your_path/foo1_import.txt';`
- manually update `foo1`.`SentenceId` based on criteria:

  `UPDATE foo1 SET SentenceId = ...` OR `INSERT ...`

Together with what was mentioned above, there are [**Best practices**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) about populating data in PostgreSQL database, which basically recommends to use `COPY` instead of series of `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I get correctly one can not use query options for import. Manually updating > 300 entries will be hard.

Comment: You can use it for import, just not in one step . As I mentioned above you need to generate file for import